# can not access Heroku Postgres's data using herokuCli

Tags: heroku-postgres, prisma, heroku-cli

I have setted up a Heroku Postgres app and did connect it (via docker) using prisma init. All is fine, i can connect the app at http://localhost:4466, do a standart mutation using the preset User schema, then query the users data.

I turn down the container, delete any volume (docker-compose down -d), turn it on again, re-query the users query, i got back the users data as expected. Look like all works fine.

The problem come up when i want to check the data inside the Heroku's database. I did connect using pgAdmin, but nothing showed up. Seeing all the issues with pgAdim on Google, i decided to use HerokuCli. All works fine, i connect my account, connect the database using the HerokuCli credential, i can see the User table's name (\d), but when i query the tuples (select * from User), it s blank....

[terminal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymlsc.png)

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query `select * from User` returned nothing as i forgot ';' at the end.

The query `select * from User;` works but return the database owner id

The good queries to get the table's content using HerokuCli's Postgres app (which i guess are simply the Postgres syntax ?..) are: `select * from "User";`  or `select * from public."User";`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I gave up on this. Installed pgAdmin [link](https://www.pgadmin.org/) and connected to the DB trough my machine.